# Spring scheduled tasks - making them run every day at 3am?

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I have the following line of scheduling in spring...

```
        <task:scheduled ref="jobService" method="jobToRun" cron="0 0 7 ? * MON" />
```

I now have the need to make this happen every single day (including weekends) at 3am - I've no idea what I am looking at here, Cron has always kind of escaped me = I know I need to change the "0 0 7 ? * MON" string, but I have no idea what it should be... All help appreciated! Thanks in advance. I tried googling this, but there seemes to be multiple formats etc - I am not too sure what exactly I need it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `cron`  as shown below:

```
<task:scheduled ref="jobService" method="jobToRun" cron="0 0 3 * * *" />
```

The cron expression represents the below time:

0 - 0 seconds

0 - 0 minutes

**3 - 3AM**

Rest of the `*` fields in the `cron` indicates all over the year, all weeks and days

I suggest you understand the cron expression patterns from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)

Comment: Perfect, thanks - will read the link this evening, too - I just needed to get this working first was all, and Cron is a mystery to me at present.